# Remove rows from tab delimited files based on a common column with another file

Tags: text-processing, columns

I am having trouble processing a tab delimited file based on the common column `Column_4` with another file.

One file is likely to be very small (less than 100 rows), the second one, however, will be well over 80,000 (both with approximately 30 columns).

`file1.txt`:

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
A1          B1          C1          D1
A2          B2          C2          D2
A3          B3          C3          D3
```

`file2.txt`:

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
Aa1          Bb1          Cc1          Dd1
Aa2          Bb2          Cc2          D2
Aa3          Bb3          Cc3          Dd3
```

`desired_output.txt`:

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
Aa2          Bb2         Cc2          D2
```

I've tried a series of `cut`, `grep`, `awk`, etc., but can't seem to get it right.

The ultimate goal is to remove all the non-matching rows from `file2.txt`, then compare the output to `file1.txt`.

Comment: What is non-matching rows from `file2.txt`?

Comment: Thanks Gnouc.  I adjusted the Columns to better illustrate what I am looking for.  Basically, if Column_4 from file2.txt does not match Column_4 from file1.txt... I do not want to see it.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood well your question, it sounds like a typical
[join ("Join lines on a common field")](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html) use case :

```
join --header -j 4 -t $'\t' file1.txt file2.txt
```

You get 7 columns for each matching row.

Here is what I get (for the slightly modified data, see below):

```
Column_4    Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_1    Column_2    Column_3
D2  A2  B2  C2  Aa2 Bb2 Cc2
D3  A3  B3  C3  Aa3 Bb3 Cc3
D8  A8  B8  C8  Aa8 Bb8 Cc8
```

(sorry the tabs don't display pretty here):

Column_4 is your matching value, and comes first.
You can compare the values of the other columns as you requested in *your goal*.

If you only want the second table columns, use:

```
join --header  -j 4 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 -t $'\t' file1.txt file2.txt
```

However, `join` expects its input files to be sorted so you need to pass them through `sort` and sort them on the 4th field first:

```
join --header  -j 4 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 -t $'\t' <(sort -k4 file1.txt) <(sort -k 4 file2.txt)
```

For a better demo, I suggest slightly different source files
(hem, that was before you edited them)

file1:

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
A0  B0  C0  D0
A2  B2  C2  D2
A3  B3  C3  D3
A8  B8  C8  D8
```

file2:

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
Aa1 Bb1 Cc1 D1
Aa2 Bb2 Cc2 D2
Aa3 Bb3 Cc3 D3
Aa4 Bb4 Cc4 D4
Aa5 Bb5 Cc5 D5
Aa6 Bb6 Cc6 D6
Aa7 Bb7 Cc7 D7
Aa8 Bb8 Cc8 D8
Aa9 Bb9 Cc9 D9
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$4];next}; $4 in a' OFS="\t" file1 file2
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3    Column_4
Aa2          Bb2          Cc2          D2
```

Comment: Is this expected to function similarly with a file with 30+ columns?  I get different results when I change the $4 to $18.

Comment: @cmart2112 yes, it should work. Try adding `-F"\t"` to make awk read tab separated values. If you have spaces in your fields, that might confuse things.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks, missing the tab delimiter. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Gnouc:  Thanks. I am getting close.  But somehow I am getting the entire contents of file2.txt, not just the row that matches in Column_4.  GNU Awk 3.1.8 if that helps

Comment: Can you give some actual data?

Comment: I found if I remove all of the whitespaces with: `sed 's/ //g'`, your solution works perfectly.  However, I would like to find a way to perform this without having to remove them as some columns require a space.